# Characterization of linear transformation with same Kernel and range

Tags: linear-algebra

Can we characterize class of all linear transformation T:V -> V for which Kernel(T) = Range(T)?

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$$\ker T\subset \text{Im}\,T\implies \forall\,x\in\ker T\,\exists\,y\;\;s.t.\;\;x=Ty\implies 0=Tx=T^2y$$

$$\text{Im}\,T\subset\ker T\implies\;\forall y\in\text{Im}\,T\;\exists x\in\ker T\,,\,v\,\;\;s.t.\;\;Tv=y=x\implies T^2v=Tx=0$$